# Abstract class in Java.

Tags: java, scjp

Wat does it mean by indirect Instantiation of abstract class ? how do
we achieve this ?
as i tried few times like .. it gives error has any one done something regarding this

```
    abstract class hello //abstract class declaration 
    { 
    void leo() {}
    }             


    abstract class test {} //2'nd abstract class 


    class dudu {  //main class 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
    hello d = new test() ;  // tried here 
    }

    }
```

Comment: test doesn't extend hello, so referring to an object of type test using a variable of type hello doesn't make sense. And abstract classes can't be instantiated, by definition. So calling new test() doesn't make sense either. Please re-read your text book about inheritance and abstract classes. And respect the Java naming conventions: classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: If you subclass an abstract class with a concrete class, and override all its abstract methods, when you instantiate the subclass, you automatically indirectly instantiate the abstract class. The term "indirectly" is not common, but i guess you probably mean that, since there is no way to instantiate an abstract class directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't instantiate an abstract class. The whole idea of Abstract class is to declare something which is common among subclasses and then extend it.

```
  public abstract class Human {
         // This class can't be instantiated, there can't be an object called Human
         }

  public Male extends Human {
         // This class can be instantiated, getting common features through extension from Human class
   } 

  public Female extends Human {
        // This class can be instantiated, getting common features through extension from Human class

   }
```

For more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: i am basically asking about " indirect instanciation " ?

Comment: @Akshay: and we don't know what you mean by that. Please post a reference which makes sense. Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Akshay Why do you mean by Indirect Instantiation? If you mean declaring a reference variable and then assigning it a different object. That could happen if the classes have an Inheritance relationship. e.g: SuperClass A = new SubClass();

Answer (score 2):

We can't instantiate an abstract class .If we want than we have to extend it.

Answer (score 2):

> Wat does it mean my indirect instanciation of abstract class ? how do we achieve this ?

I'd need to see the context in which that phrase is used, but I expect that "indirect instantiation"  means instantiation of a non-abstract class that extends your abstract class.

For example

```
public abstract class A {
    private int a;
    public A(int a) {
       this.a = a;
    }
    ...
}

public B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(42);
    } 
    ...
}

B b = new B();    // This is an indirect instantiation of A
                  // (sort of ....)

A a = new A(99);  // This is a compilation error.  You cannot
                  // instantiate an abstract class directly.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create instance of abstract class, I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
abstract class hello //abstract class declaration 
{ 
    void leo() {}
}             

class test extends hello 
{
    void leo() {} // Custom test's implementation of leo method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot create object for Abstract class in java.
Refer this link-http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html